# GCP Colab + Vertex AI + Matching Engine giving grpc error

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am building a Q&A chatbot using Vertex AI in Google Colab but getting below error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
   1002             return state.response
   1003     else:
-> 1004         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
   1005 
   1006 

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:10.46.0.5:10000: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:10.46.0.5:10000: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-08-22T17:19:56.056416552+00:00"}"
```

This is the code snippet causing the error:

`from vertexai.preview.language_models import TextGenerationModel

matching_engine_response=matching_engine_search(question)

prompt=f"""
Follow exactly those 3 steps:

1. Read the context below and aggregrate this data
   Context : {matching_engine_response}
2. Answer the question using only this context
3. Show the source for your answers
   User Question: {question}

If you don't have any context and are unsure of the answer, reply that you don't know about this topic.
"""

model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained(TEXT_GENERATION_MODEL)
response = model.predict(
prompt,
temperature=0.2,
top_k=40,
top_p=.8,
max_output_tokens=1024,
)

print(f"Question: \n{question}")
print(f"Response: \n{response.text}")`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I tried setting grpc resolver environment variable to native but it didn't help